# How to Write a qUnit test for a jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, qunit

I'm starting to get deep into qUnit, but I ran into an issue I'm not sure how to properly write a test for.

The function basically alerts a jQuery UI dialog when a button is pushed. Here is my qUnit Test:

```
test( "If Text is Type, and Control is Textbox, Check Alert if Two Values are Present",  function() {

    //Add New Row
    $('.button').click();


    equal($('#jquery_ui_id').is(':visible'), true, "Prompt is Shown" );

});
```

The issue is that the test passes in qUnit, **but only on reload.** So it always fails when I first run the test, then succeeds while I reload it.

Does anyone know what is going on here, or has ran into this before?

Comment: this might be related to not properly cleaning up previous tests - make sure you're removing any elements you add to the DOM at the end of each test.

Comment: This seems to be the issue! I thought qUnit did this automatically with every 'test' module. Is this not true? (If you write this in an answer as well, I'll be sure to select it as the correct one!)

Comment: This question provide detail on why  the dom isn't reset. To make in short, JQuery add html code outside of #qunit-fixture

Comment: Missing link in previous comment : 
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898593/qunit-twitter-bootstrap-modals-writing-outside-of-qunit-fixture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally when a qUnit test toggles between failing and succeeding when you reload the page, it means you're not properly cleaning up after your tests and they are conflicting with each other.

If you add elements to the DOM and manipulate in a module or test without using the special `#qunit-fixture` element, you should be removing them at the end of that module so the next one can start fresh.

For more information, see the section on [keeping qUnit tests atomic](http://qunitjs.com/cookbook/#keeping-tests-atomic).

> QUnit will reset the elements inside the #qunit-fixture element after
>   each test, removing any events that may have existed. As long as you
>   use elements only within this fixture, you don't have to manually
>   clean up after your tests to keep them atomic.

Answer (score -1):

had the same issue and I was sure to render all my dom under element #qunit-fixture.
While investigating, I found out that **JQuery-UI add elements for the dialog directly into `<body>`.**

So **one way around this would be to render #qunit-fixture before the body.** In my case I have javascript script inside the body and this doesn't go under #qunit-fixture. So I would need to remove script from body before that.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <div id="qunit-fixture"><!--Wrap whole body into fixture-->
       <body>
       </body>
   </div>
</html>
```

**Another way around is to manually remove added stuff in the teardown.**

```
module("SomeModule",
{
    teardown: function ()
    {
        $('.ui-front').remove();//Need to be reset manually, because jquery dialog add these outside of fixture...
    }
});
```

To cleanup added elements, we use the fact that they all have the class "ui-front".